# Baskerville font with math compatibility

Tags: fonts

I would appreciate a little help producing a document with the same main font and math font and symbols used on this page from a book by P.J. Nahin.
[image]

I've done some digging and found that the main font is New Baskerville ITC. This font is also used in the equations. I'm not entirely sure if there is a version of this font for LaTeX which comes with math support and the same symbols (integral symbol etc.), but if someone could locate such a font then that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can you Baskerville clones and see if they fit your needs. Two packages seem to have math support: [`baskervaldx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/baskervaldx), [`baskervaldadf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/baskervaldadf),  and [`baskervillef`](https://ctan.org/pkg/baskervillef) (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

I use the [mathspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) package to accomplish using different fonts in my documents. You need to have the font installed on your computer first and you need to use the correct name for the font. My example uses Times New Roman since it should work for most people. Change the font name to any other font you have installed.

You also need to compile with XeLaTeX.

Otherwise, it is quite simple:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
and so, with $A=1/2t_T$, we have \par
etc.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Baskervaldx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/baskervaldx) and [`newtxmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) with the `baskervaldx` option to get the math letters from baskervaldx.

```
\documentclass[intlimits]{article} % passes intlimits option to amsmath
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}
\newcommand{\du}{\,d\mkern-1.5mu u}

\begin{document}
and so, with $A=1/2t_T$, we have
    \[y(t) = \int_0^t v(u)\du = v_T\int_0^1 \tanh(u/2t_T)\du = v_T\cdot 2t_T(\ln\{\cosh(u/2t_T)\})\vert_0^t,\]
or
\begin{equation}
    y(t) = 2v_Tt_T\ln\{\cosh(t/2t_T)\}. \tag{5.7}
\end{equation}
You'll notice that (5.7) says $y(t=0)=0$, as it should.

Equation (5.7), simple as it may look, has great surprises for most who encounter it. For example, let's go back to what Galileo had to say about two falling balls:

\begin{quote}
\small
Aristotle says \dots
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]